# How do you enter a half comma (顿号, dùnhào) with Google Pinyin IME and a French keyboard?

Tags: writing, input-methods, punctuation

I have a laptop with a UK English version of Windows and a French keyboard (AZERTY...). I have been using the Google Pinyin IME for some time now but I can't figure out how to enter a "half comma" (顿号, dùnhào, i.e. this type of comma: **、**). There are explanations for non-AZERTY keyboards (e.g. at [LaoshiLink](http://laoshilink.org/laoshilink/GoogleIME.html)) but I haven't found any for French keyboards. (I did a web search in French but I wasn't lucky.)

Comment: 顿号 is in the symbol list in Google Pinyin IME. It wasn't there?

Comment: It's not the | \ button?

Comment: @user3306356 No, I tried all combinations of `AltGr` with other keys; this did not give me a dun comma.

Comment: It's less likely to be a combination key than just a key on its own. You might want to just try all ,./-:;'"_\|~]]{}#%^*+=.,' keys and see what you get

Comment: @user3306356 No, that gives me just the characters that are on those keys, i.e. the same output as when Google Pinyin is not running at all. Anyway, I found a way. See my response.

Comment: I know this is not what you were looking for but I'd suggest you try sogou's IME - you might have an easier time with a Chinese-made IME

Comment: @user3306356 Thanks. I am aware of Sogou but I haven't tried it yet. I will see if it works better for the dun comma and then update my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since I figured it out after some more searching and trying, here is the answer:

After starting Google Pinyin IME, right-click on the **keyboard button** (**软键盘** ruǎnjiànpán: software keyboard). From the menu that appears, choose **标点符号** (biāodiǎn fúhào: punctuation marks). This will bring up a keyboard on the screen; the dun comma is on the top row, on the same key as the number 2. You can than enter the dun comma using either the software keyboard or your hardware keyboard. You can then close the software keyboard again by clicking on the keyboard button.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of keyboard shortcuts to do this.

Comment: @帅气型男 The key to the left of F1 is ESC (or `échap` in French). Shift + ESC does not result in any punctuation. The key below ESC gives ² (regardless whether Google Pinyin is running or not.

Comment: There is a key on the left of the number key 1. Use CTRL + `, it may be what you want.

Comment: @帅气型男 Thanks again for your suggestions. The key to the left of `1` is `²` (a superscript 2). 
I have tried Ctrl + `²`, Alt + `²`, Ctrl + Alt + `²`, AltGr + `²`, Ctrl + AltGr + `²`, Ctrl + Shift + `²`， Alt + Shift + `²`, AltGr + Shift + `²`, and none of these key combinations results in any output.

Comment: Could you show us how your keyboard looks like? It seems that the positions do not match with mine.

Comment: @帅气型男 See the image "AZERTY layout used in France" in the Wikipedia article [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY).

Comment: Oh, I am sorry! The French keyboard is too different from the English one. Sadly using your French keyboard, there really are no keyboard shortcuts.